# Summing Unique Integers in Dictionary with Duplicate Values

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a .txt file that I opened and converted to a list using the .readlines method.

```
with open('superheroes.txt') as f:
    hero = f.readlines()
```

I read it into an empty dictionary and since the file had a lot of duplicate strings but unique numbers, I chose to make the unique integers the keys and the duplicate strings the values using this code:

```
heroes = {}

for i in range(len(hero)):
    name, num = hero[i].strip().split("\t")

    heroes[int(num)] = name
```

The output of the print statement gives something similar to this:

{1867: 'Superman', 2904: 'Batman', 783: 'Wonderwoman', 4637: 'Superman', 8392: 'Batman', etc}

So far, I was able to append all the keys of a certain value into a unique list and manually sorted them using a for loop and an if statement:

```
superheroes = list(set(heroes.values())) #Gets all the unique values into one list

print(superheroes.sort()) #Ensures that the positions don't change when sorting

supes = []
bats = []
wonder = []
flash = []
cap = []

for entry in heroes:
    if heroes[entry] == superheroes[0]:
        bats.append(entry)
    elif heroes[entry] == superheroes[1]:
        cap.append(entry)
    elif heroes[entry] == superheroes[2]:
        flash.append(entry)
    elif heroes[entry] == superheroes[3]:
        supes.append(entry)
    else:
        wonder.append(entry)

print("People Saved: ")
print("Batman ", sum(bats))
print("Captain America ", sum(cap))
print("Flash ", sum(flash))
print("Superman ", sum(supes))
print("Wonderwoman ", sum(wonder))
```

After this, I would have to find a method to put these values into a new dictionary. My task is to sum the keys and only have the values shown once. Meaning that all the people they saved must be a single integer value that can then be summed together with another dictionary like this.

How can I sum all the keys of each unique value together and display them within the dictionary? I can only use vanilla Python 3.x code and no other modules can be imported.

Comment: I'm not allowed to import any other modules. Hence, I can't import defaultdict from collections.

Comment: Where exactly would that go in the code? During the for loop reading it in?

Comment: Nvm. It gave me what I needed. So now I would do sum(heroes.values()) to get the dictionary with all the values added up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure to get the full picture of your question. You are looking for a way to sum all the key and display them as a dictionary where the key would be the value of your input and the value would be the sum of the key of your input.

Would this be helpful

```
input = {1867: 'Superman', 2904: 'Batman', 783: 'Wonderwoman', 4637: 'Superman', 8392: 'Batman'}
output = {v:k for k, v in input.items()}
```

This produce

```
>>> {'Superman': 4637, 'Batman': 8392, 'Wonderwoman': 783}
```

Comment: I get an error that says 'unhashable type' list. I used dictionary comprehension in a different way though. I used {k:sum(v) for k,v in heroes.items()} after someone told me a method to get all the values of each key only shown once.

Comment: Another user just gave me exactly what I needed and then I used your method and it worked. Thanks! :)